# Don't display swatches on product listing

Tags: attributes, product-list, swatches

Basically i can see swatches on both the product listing and the product page.
How do i remove the ones on the product listing, so I only have them on the product page

I only want the swatches to be displayed here.
[image]

And i dont want the swatches to be displayed on the page below.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `System > Configuration > Catalog > Configurable Swatches` set `Product Attribute to Use for Swatches in Product Listing` to `-- Please Select --`

Comment: Thank you, for the quick and precise answer.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks. Although I'm not sure what Magento version you're using. I can't find this option in Magento 2.1.3. But I can edit the product attribute to set `Storefront Propertes` -> `Used in Product Listing` to get the same result.

Comment: As of Magento 2.3, this has been moved to `Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront > Show Swatches on Product List`. Not sure when this was changed but I am on **2.3.1**